# snowflake query optimization

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization

Tell me please, where can I read about query optimization in a snowflake?  maybe best practices?  especially regarding left join

maybe a book or a video… previously i worked in sql server

can you explain which SQL script is better and why?

`DELETE FROM dwh.sandbox.test  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL  FROM DWH.SANDBOX._tmp_test s WHERE test.calculation_id = s.calculation_id )`

OR

`DELETE FROM dwh.sandbox.test t USING DWH.SANDBOX._tmp_test t2 WHERE t.calculation_id = t2.calculation_id`

Comment: Please share specific use case, any query or slowness you experience. Remember that snowflake is a bit different then conventional RDBMSs in that it operates how data is distributed in micro partitions. Try looking into plan and see which part of the plan is fetching or returning more data and what filter you can use there to restrict or optimize it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html

Comment: can you explain which SQL script is better and why? 

`DELETE FROM dwh.sandbox.test 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                 FROM DWH.SANDBOX._tmp_test s
                 WHERE test.calculation_id = s.calculation_id
                 )`

OR

`DELETE FROM dwh.sandbox.test t
USING DWH.SANDBOX._tmp_test t2
WHERE t.calculation_id = t2.calculation_id`